# Select rows in pandas dframe where the given input list is a subset of lists in dframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dframe like this :

```
Name Nos
Jack [4,2,3,12]
Adam [5,6,4,2,3]
John [1,3,4]
```

What is the quickest way (shorts code) to go about, where the result should be the dframe containing rows Jack and Adam when input is `[4,2,3]` ? I have tried to use where, but I'm not quite able to get the right solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to match the input list ```[4,2,3]``` in the *nos* of the dataframe and return corresponding rows and if so, do they need to be in the same order or just in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below code if you need to have the values `[4, 2, 3]` consecutively together appearing in the list:

```
input_list = [4, 2, 3]
def func(df, l):
    return df[df['Nos'].astype(str).str.contains(str(l)[1:-1])]
print(func(df, input_list))
```

If you just want the values to be in there, use:

```
input_list = [4, 2, 3]
def func(df, l):
    return df[df['Nos'].astype(str).str.contains('&'.join(l))]
print(func(df, input_list))
```

Comment: `'&'.join(l)` ? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
inp = [4,2,3]
df["Flag"] = [True if set(inp).issubset(i) else False for i in df["Nos"].values]

df_new = df[df["Flag"]==True].drop("Flag", axis=1)
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
    Name    Nos
0   Jack    [4, 2, 3, 12]
1   Adam    [5, 6, 4, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lambda expression:

```
input = [4,2,3]
df_output = df[df.apply(lambda x: all(elem in x['Nos'] for elem in input), axis=1)]
print(df_output)
```

Output:

```
   Name              Nos
0  Jack    [4, 2, 3, 12]
1  Adam  [5, 6, 4, 2, 3]
[Finished in 0.4s]
```